# How do I calculate max/min of a function

Tags: convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

Good evening,

I'm studying integrals at the moment, and right now I'm studying a part where our teacher shows us how to see if an integral exists (is not infinite or 0) by comparing to the integral of a max or min integral.

For example in order to solve this:

$\int_2^\infty\frac{\cos{x}}{x^2}dx$

the example shows that the main part of the integral is equal and less than $\frac{1}{x^2}$ for $x\in[2, +\infty)$ so

$0 \le \frac{|\cos{x}|}{x^2} \le \frac{1}{x^2}$

thus saying that the $\int_2^\infty\frac{1}{x^2}dx$ exists (and is $\frac{1}{2}$) so the starting integral exists as well.

This makes perfect sense to me, and I can see how $\frac{1}{x^2}$ is equal or larger than $\frac{|\cos{x}|}{x^2}$.

However, what baffles me is the next 2 examples.

a) $\int_1^\infty\frac{3x^2+2x+1}{x^3+6x^2+x+4}dx$

b) $\int_1^\infty\frac{3x+1}{\sqrt{x^5+4x^3+5x}}dx$

For which he says that for

a) $\frac{3x^2+2x+1}{x^3+6x^2+x+4} \ge \frac{1}{4x}, x\in[1,+\infty)$

b) $0 \le\frac{3x+1}{\sqrt{x^5+4x^3+5x}} \le \frac{4}{x^{3/2}}$

What I can't understand or find any way to see how, is how he came up with $\frac{1}{4x}$ and $\frac{4}{x^{3/2}}$.

Is this a specific routine I have to follow somehow to find those max and min functions?

Thanks in advance for any help and explanation.

Comment: Generally, a polynomial behaves like it's highest-degree term for large inputs, so $\frac{3x^2+2x+1}{x^3+6x^2+x+4}$ behaves like $\frac{3x^2}{x^3}=\frac{3}{x}$ for lage $x$, so then you just need to play around till you find a sufficient factor such that "behaves like" turns into a definite lower bound for suitable values of $x$.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. I was mixing things up.